# Change background color javascript in specific order

Tags: javascript

I'm fairly new to JavaScript, and I need a bit of help. I want it so that my web page's background color changes from `#003372` to `#FFFFFF` and then to `#BE2E37` in that specific order (every 1000 milliseconds), without generating them all at random. Reason why is because I made a flash movie on my website and I want it to match with the colors that appear.

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function changebackground() { 
            var colors = ["#003372","#FFFFFF","#BE2E37"];

        setInterval(function() { 
            var bodybgarrayno = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
            var selectedcolor = colors[bodybgarrayno];
            document.body.style.background = selectedcolor;
        }, 2000);
    }
    </script>
```

HTML:

```
<body onload = changebackground();>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function changebackground() { 
    var colors = ["#003372","#FFFFFF","#BE2E37"], iColor = 0;

    setInterval(function() { 
        if (iColor > (colors.length - 1)) iColor = 0;

        var selectedcolor = colors[iColor];
        document.body.style.background = selectedcolor;
        console.log(iColor);
        iColor += 1;

    }, 1000);
}
```

You need to declare and increment the value of `iColor` in each interval and set back to 0 when reach the end of the array length

<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g4ahX/2/)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with CSS

```
@keyframe changeBackground {

0%{background-color:#003372;}

50%{background-color:#FFFFFF;}

100%{background-color:#BE2E37;}

}

#yourbackgrounddiv {
animation: changeBackground 1s infinte linear;

}
```

This will do a smooth transition, if you want it to be a hard change you can add a "step" option to the animation tag.
you would also need vendor specific prefixes. More information...
http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/animation/

Answer (score 1):

```
function changebackground() {
    var colors = ["#003372","#FFFFFF","#BE2E37"];
    // declare index variable outside of interval enclosure,
    // so it's value persists between calls
    var index = 0;

    setInterval(function() { 
        // magic maths to determine the current index to use...
        // will be last index plus one, until on last in array
        // when it will be zero again...
        index = (index+1)%colors.length;
        var selectedcolor = colors[index];
        document.body.style.background = selectedcolor;
    }, 1000);
}
```